How to set dialog contents to align to screen bottom when hiding navigation bar in BottomSheetDialog?

In default, the navigation bar shows below BottomSheetDialog. When I hide the navigation bar, the content of BottomSheetDialog doesn't align to the screen bottom. As the picture shows below:

The second picture shows that there is a padding in the bottom of the BottomSheetDialog. The padding's height equals to the height of navigation bar. And when you swipe from bottom to up at the bottom of the screen, the navigation bar can show up.
The question is how to remove the padding of the dialog bottom to let the content to align the screen bottom?

Well, after trying many times, I find a way to solve the problem.
Just removing the padding after the dialog shows up. Like this:
    protected fun hideNavigationBar() {
        NavigationUtil.hideBottomNavigationBar(window)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val container = findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.container)
            container?.let {
                it.post {
                    // When hide navigation bar, set the bottom padding to 0
                    it.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
                }
            }
        }
    }

You can call hideNavigationBar() before the dialog is showing.
